# Batch rename list of files to totally different names using R

Tags: r, file, batch-file, rename

I have 330 files that i would like to rename using R. I saved the original names and the new names in a .csv file. I used a script which does not give an error but it does not change the names.

Here is a sample of the new names:(df1)

```
D:\Modis_EVI\Original\EVI_Smoothed\ MODIS_EVI_20010101.tif
D:\Modis_EVI\Original\EVI_Smoothed\ MODIS_EVI_20010117.tif
D:\Modis_EVI\Original\EVI_Smoothed\ MODIS_EVI_20010201.tif
```

And a sample of the original names:(df2)

```
D:\Modis_EVI\Original\EVI_Smoothed\ MODIS.2001001.yL1600.EVI.tif
D:\Modis_EVI\Original\EVI_Smoothed\ MODIS.2001033.yL1600.EVI.tif
D:\Modis_EVI\Original\EVI_Smoothed\ MODIS.2001049.yL1600.EVI.tif
```

Then here is the script i'm using:

```
csv_dir   <-  "D:\\"
df1        <- read.csv(paste(csv_dir,"New_names.csv",sep=""), header=TRUE, sep=",")        # read csv
hdfs       <- df1$x                                 
hdfs       <- as.vector(hdfs)                                  
df2        <- read.csv(paste(csv_dir,"smoothed.csv",sep=""), header=TRUE, sep=",")        # read csv
tifs       <- df2$x                                 
tifs       <- as.vector(tifs)                       
for (i in 1:length(hdfs)){ 
  setwd("D:\\Modis_EVI\\Original\\EVI_Smoothed\\")
  file.rename(from =tifs[i], to = hdfs[i]) 
}
```

Any advice please?

Comment: It would be quite helpful when you provided sample data of your `*.csv` files...

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks fr the suggestion, i have attached sample of the new and the original names.

Comment: Are the spaces really contained in the data? or did they happen unintentionally when copying them to this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mix up the old and the new files, and you are trying to use rename the new file (names), which do not exist, to the old file names. This might work

```
file.rename(from =hdfs[i], to = tifs[i])
```

A general approach would go like this:

```
setwd("D:\\Modis_EVI\\Original\\EVI_Smoothed\\")

fin <- list.files(pattern='tif$')
fout <- gsub("_EVI_", ".", fin)
fout <- gsub(".tif", "yL1600.EVI.tif", fout)

for (i in 1:length(fin)){ 
   file.rename(from=fin[i], to= fout[i]) 
}
```

To fix your script (do you really need .csv files?)

```
setwd("D:\\Modis_EVI\\Original\\EVI_Smoothed\\")

froms  <- read.csv("d:/New_names.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
froms <- as.vector(froms$x)
```

First check if they exist:

```
all(file.exists(froms))
```

Perhaps you need to trim the names (remove whitespace) -- that is what the examples you give suggest

```
library(raster)
froms <- trim(froms) 
all(file.exists(froms))
```

If they exist

```
tos  <- read.csv("d:/smoothed.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
tos <- as.vector(tos$x)                       
# tos <- trim(tos)

for (i in 1:length(froms)) { 
  file.rename(froms[i], tos[i]) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @RobertH I followed your suggestion and it worked.. I think the files names were not existing as it had spaces in between.